# Why is my JS for loop not working? (returns "undefinded"

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, string-length

I was doing a JS exercise and it asked me to return a number combination in reversed order (1234 => 4321) so as always I tried do to it myself without looking for a solution and I came with:

```
function rev(n){
    for(i=n.length;i=0;i--){
       var reversed = reversed + n[i];
    }
    return reversed;
}
console.log(rev("test"));
```

But when I run this on VSCode it returns undefined to me and I do not understand which part of my code is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: you want i>=0 as the end condition

Comment: Have a look at how variables that are defined with `var` work. After that have a look at how `for` works.

Comment: And you need to initialize `reversed` to `""` before using it. And you need to declare `i`, and you need to start from `n.length - 1`.

Comment: @SuperStormer This change alone won't change the output of `undefined`

Comment: I believe you should start at length-1, not length. Indexes start at zero, so the indexes on "test" are 0, 1, 2, and 3. But the length is 4.

Comment: @SuperStormer since I am doing a decreasing loop I do not see why I would use i>=0

Comment: @skr33t You want the loop to continue as long as i>=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I understand your point. You intended to implement this and you wonder why **your** code is not working as expected. Kudos for your brave approach. Let's fix the issues you have step-by-step:

## Initial code

```
function rev(n){
    for(i=n.length;i=0;i--){
       var reversed = reversed + n[i];
    }
    return reversed;
}
console.log(rev("test"));
```

## Define reversed outside the loop

```
function rev(n){
    var reversed = "";
    for(i=n.length;i=0;i--){
        var reversed = reversed + n[i];
    }
    return reversed;
}
console.log(rev("test"));
```

Explanation: Your code recreated it inside your loop upon each step, and assuming it was not defined somehow outside the function it would crash upon the first use. You need to properly initialize it before you concatenate anything to it.

## Fix the concatenation

```
function rev(n){
    var reversed = "";
    for(i=n.length;i=0;i--){
        reversed = reversed + n[i];
    }
    return reversed;
}
console.log(rev("test"));
```

Explanation: Removed the `var` keyword inside the loop, so you reuse `reversed` and correctly concatenate `n[i]` to it.

## Properly define i

```
function rev(n){
    var reversed = "";
    for(let i = n.length - 1;i=0;i--){
        reversed = reversed + n[i];
    }
    return reversed;
}
console.log(rev("test"));
```

Explanation: You need to make sure that `i` exists as a variable. Also, we initialize it from `n.length - 1`, because indexing starts from 0, so the first element has the index of 0, the second element has the index of 1 and ... and the k'th element has the index of k-1, hence the last element of `n` is `n.length - 1` and, as you have correctly figured out, the last element must be the first element.

## Fix the continue condition

```
function rev(n){
    var reversed = "";
    for(let i = n.length - 1;i>=0;i--){
        reversed = reversed + n[i];
    }
    return reversed;
}
console.log(rev("test"));
```

Explanation: You assumed that the second statement inside the for is the end condition, but it is the exact opposite: it is the continue condition. It translates to plain words as "repeat as long as", instead of "repeat until".

## Do it defensively

```
function rev(n){
    var reversed;
    if (typeof n === "string") {
        reversed = "";
        for(let i = n.length - 1;i>=0;i--){
            reversed = reversed + n[i];
        }
    }
    return reversed;
}
console.log(rev("test"));
```

Explanation: We only do the reversion if it's a string.

## Let's support array:

```
function rev(n){
    var reversed;
    if (typeof n === "string") {
        reversed = "";
        for(let i = n.length - 1;i>=0;i--){
            reversed = reversed + n[i];
        }
    } else if (Array.isArray(n)) {
        reversed = [];
        for(let i = n.length - 1;i>=0;i--){
            reversed.push(n[i]);
        }
    }
    return reversed;
}
console.log(rev("test"));
console.log(rev(["t","e","s","t"]));
```

Explanation: The algorithm is similar for arrays as for strings, but we cope with technical differences nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

You define reversed in the `for` loop. What you need to do:

```js
function rev(n) {
  let reversed = "";
  for (let i = n.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversed = `${reversed}${n[i]}`;
  }
  return reversed;
}
console.log(rev("test"));
```

Comment: Why should I use let? I've done the exact loop I am posting to calculate if a day was a Monday given the year and it worked without using let, I want to learn JavaScript from home but the answers of the exercises I am doing on w3resource are not by chance like your answers... I feel pretty stupid for not understanding your code

Comment: You don't have to use `let` but it is almost always better than `var`. Explaining the difference here would be too long. You won't find many people using `var` nowadays so I advise you start using `let` if you plan on getting a job as a JS developer. [let vs var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Comment: @mplungjan It wouldn't, it's supposed to be given a string :)

Comment: `it asked me to return a number combination in reversed order (1234 => 4321) `

Comment: @AlexandreSenges  if you see my question I don't that I could work as a developer soon haha, but I'll read that. Where should I start learning JavaScript? Is there a better/faster way than doing +50 exercises on w3resources? They have pretty bad exercise answers + using old code.

Comment: BTW, the part I did not understand was: `${reversed}${n[i]}`

Comment: @skr33t you'll be surprised by how fast you can learn if you are determined. The way I started learning was by building my own project, I think that's a great approach because 1) it was something I was passionate about, so I kept motivated  2) You learn what really matters and not random stuff you find in exercises 3) It's something you can show and add on your resume right away :) . This syntax is called [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), it allows you to easily insert the value of a variable inside of a string.

Comment: @AlexandreSenges I have one project in mind because it does not exist at the moment but it is too much for me at the moment: a browser game with user registration for a 2vs2 game like poker with no currency involved and I planned on doing it with ReactJS, the problem is that I want it to be PoV (it is a traditional game and you communicate with winks) and my project would involve 3D work like three.js to be able to wink your teammate and to see your contender's wink maybe playing with PoV angles to make it more immersive, it only involves 36 cards on the deck and 3 cards per player.

Comment: @skr33t I think you can start by making it 2D and just local multiplayer, then build on top of that

Answer (score 1):

Must you use loop?

Code below:

```
String(1234)  // make the number a string 
.split("")    // split on char making an array
.reverse()    // reverse that array
.join("")     // join it back
```

the `+` casts the reversed string back to number

```js
console.log(
 +String(1234).split("").reverse().join("")
)
```

Comment: _"I do not understand which part of my code is wrong"_ -> _"here have some completely different code"_ - how does that help?

Comment: @AlexandreSenges Why on earth not. I could use String() too.

Comment: @AlexandreSenges so `+` must be a parseInt too?

Comment: @mplungjan I think your example was cool as a fun JS thing. I just wouldn't use operators without left operand at work. Definitely will start using in my own projects

Comment: @mplungjan What happens if you pass -1234? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your existing code as the snippet below and it will work fine

```
function rev(str){
  var n = str.split("");
  var reversed ="";
    for(i=n.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--){
       reversed +=n[i];
    }
    return reversed;
}
console.log(rev("1234"));
```

Best way to reserve string

```
const reverseStr = str => {
  var splitString = str.split("");
  var reverseArray = splitString.reverse();
  var joinArray = reverseArray.join(""); 
  return joinArray;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like so:

```js
const reverseString = text => {
  let result = "";
  for (let i = text.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    result += text[i];
  }

  return result;
};

console.log(reverseString('test'));
```